# boost::fusion accessing key type of joint view as map

Tags: c++, boost-fusion

I'm trying to convert the ash framework to c++ to incorporate to my project, my development environment is Vista 32, and Visual C++ 2008 Express, and I'm using boost_1_37_0 libs, im not planning on upgrade the environemt until i reach some results...

Given:

```
typedef Component Pcomponent;
typedef WaitForstart2 Pcomponent2;
typedef boost::fusion::pair<ComponentWONTEXISTS,Pcomponent> component_pair1;
typedef boost::fusion::pair<WaitForstart2,Pcomponent2> component_pair2;

typedef boost::fusion::map<component_pair1> componentDictType1;
typedef boost::fusion::map<component_pair2> componentDictType2;

typedef boost::fusion::joint_view<componentDictType1, componentDictType2>joincomponentDictType;
```

I'm unable to solve how to access on of the types, using at_key

```
boost::fusion::at_key<ComponentWONTEXISTS, dictionaryjoint>(boost::fusion::as_map(dictionaryjoint));
```

Thanks,

P.S: I'm on a hurry but I'll try to reformat the question on a while

Regards,

Comment: You should probably put your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's funny but i think i managed to find the solution:

```
    typedef boost::fusion::result_of::as_map<boost::fusion::joint_view<componentDictType1, componentDictType2> >::type MAPTYPE;
    MAPTYPE aDict;
    Pcomponent ptempj3 = boost::fusion::at_key<ComponentWONTEXISTS,MAPTYPE>(aDict);
```